# Divide elements and count using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, count, divide

For my list I want to apply some different style for each 4 elements.

and I tried to divide index by 4 with something like this:

```js
var e = document.querySelectorAll('.line li');
var y = [...e]; //convert to array from nodelist

function logArrayElements(element, index, array) {
  var y = index / 4;

  console.log(y);
}

  y.forEach(logArrayElements);
```

```css
.mainUl{
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
ulParent{float: left;}

.line{
  list-style: none;
  }
  .line li{
    padding: 10px; 
    border: 1px solid orange;
    float: left;
    }
```

```html
<ul class="mainUl">
 <li class="ulParent">
 <ul class="line">
  <li>q</li>
  <li>w</li>
  <li>e</li>
  <li>r</li>
    <li>x</li>
  <li>y</li>
  <li>q</li>
  <li>z</li>
 </ul>
 </li>
 <li class="ulParent">
 <ul class="line">
  <li>q</li>
  <li>w</li>
  <li>e</li>
  <li>r</li>
    <li>x</li>
  <li>y</li>
  <li>q</li>
  <li>z</li>
 </ul>
 </li>
 <li class="ulParent">
 <ul class="line">
  <li>q</li>
  <li>w</li>
  <li>e</li>
  <li>r</li>
    <li>x</li>
  <li>y</li>
  <li>q</li>
  <li>z</li>
 </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

but is not really working.

So what I want is to count elements from 4 to 4 and apply a different css style for each group of four elements.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in plain ol' css.

First for the JS answer:

You first want to actually loop through the "lines" and then the items within them:

```
const lines = [...document.querySelectorAll('.line')];

lines.forEach(function (line) {
    // should get you your 0, .25, .5, .75 etc...
    [...line.querySelectorAll('li')].forEach(logArrayElements);
});
```

---

Now for the CSS fun:

Basically can use the `nth-child` method, the way I did it here was crude, but it is a start.

```css
.mainUl {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
ulParent {
  float: left;
}
.line {
  list-style: none;
}
.line li {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  float: left;
}

.line li:nth-child(n) {
    background: red;
}
.line li:nth-child(n+5) {
    background: purple;
}
.line li:nth-child(n+9) {
    background: green;
}
.line li:nth-child(n+13) {
    background: grey;
}
/// etc
```

```html
<ul class="mainUl">
  <li class="ulParent">
    <ul class="line">
      <li>q</li>
      <li>w</li>
      <li>e</li>
      <li>r</li>
      <li>x</li>
      <li>y</li>
      <li>q</li>
      <li>z</li>
      <li>q</li>
      <li>w</li>
      <li>e</li>
      <li>r</li>
      <li>x</li>
      <li>y</li>
      <li>q</li>
      <li>z</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="ulParent">
    <ul class="line">
      <li>q</li>
      <li>w</li>
      <li>e</li>
      <li>r</li>
      <li>x</li>
      <li>y</li>
      <li>q</li>
      <li>z</li>
      <li>q</li>
      <li>w</li>
      <li>e</li>
      <li>r</li>
      <li>x</li>
      <li>y</li>
      <li>q</li>
      <li>z</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="ulParent">
    <ul class="line">
      <li>q</li>
      <li>w</li>
      <li>e</li>
      <li>r</li>
      <li>x</li>
      <li>y</li>
      <li>q</li>
      <li>z</li>
      <li>q</li>
      <li>w</li>
      <li>e</li>
      <li>r</li>
      <li>x</li>
      <li>y</li>
      <li>q</li>
      <li>z</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I know I can do this with nth-child css but I want to iterate through elements using javascript.

Comment: @RulerNature See the first part of my answer :-)

Comment: I saw it but is to much for me :)) the way is written  maybe if you give me more details

Comment: @RulerNature basically loop through the outer elements, and then the inner elements (then your indexes will be based off the outer lists instead of the list items as a whole on the page)

Comment: Yes I saw that but actually I want to iterate through elements, I have used indexex because I don't know other way to do that. So If I use a querySelectorAll will return all elements li but what I want is to return 4 elements li, other 4 elements li, other 4 and so on.

Comment: Then you can use the `nth-child` from css ;-)

Comment: but is not possible to do something like: var e = document.querySelectorAll('.line li');
var y = [...e];  console.log( y / 4 )

Comment: @RulerNature what would that do for you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122126/discussion-between-rulernature-and-neal).